# Passing data when dismissing Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I want to pass data to the root view controller, which is `ViewController` after the previous one is dismissed, I chose to use delegation to solve this problem in this way: 
Scheme:

ViewController -> SearchViewController

`SearchViewController` produces data and dismisses

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, IsAbleToReceiveData {    
@IBAction func addButton_touchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoSearchViewController", sender: nil)
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoSearchViewController" {
        let vc2 = SearchViewController()
        vc2.delegate = self
    }
}


func passData(city: cityObject) {
        print(city.cityName)

    }
}
```

The protocol is declared:

```
protocol IsAbleToReceiveData: class {
   func passData(city : cityObject)
}
```

In the `SearchViewController` I have:

```
weak var delegate: IsAbleToReceiveData?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let citySelected: cities?
    citySelected = self.citiesQueried[indexPath.row]
    RequestAPI.convertData(city: citySelected!) { (city) in

        self.delegate?.passData(city: city)
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I try to print the data in the function in `ViewController` nothing is printed even though in `SearchViewController` *convertData* method is returning a cityObject.
How can I pass the data to `ViewController` after dismissing?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: you can use NotificationCenter for that senario.

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha `NotificationCenter` is the worst choice for objects which are related to each other. Especially in Swift callback closures should be preferred over protocol/delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```swift
 let vc2 = SearchViewController()
 vc2.delegate = self
```

with

```swift
 if let vc2 = segue.destination as? SearchViewController {
    vc2.delegate = self
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if let searchVC = segue.destination as? SearchViewController {
      searchVC.delegate = self
}
```